# Overlaying images works in Chrome/FF/Edge but not IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overlay

I use the following to overlay two images:
Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u6y92hmL/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay-single">
  <img class="top" src=http://lorempixel.com/100/100/>
  <img class="bottom" src=https://placehold.it/300x200>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay-single {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay-single .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

In Chrome, FireFox, and Edge it works perfectly with the top image sticking to the top left corner of the bottom image. But in Internet Explorer the top image is left justified.

IS there any way I can get IE to behave the same way?

Comment: I see the problem, and I don't have a solution (yet), but I just want to remark that it's very, very dangerous to omit the quotes around attribute values like that. Please make it a habit to always use quotes around attribute values (even if you're pretty sure they're not needed), then you won't run into problems.

Comment: @Mr Lister, thanks. I'd like to say I fat-fingered it when I did the copy paste for the example but when I went back and looked at the original code apparently I did leave them out. Oops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to w3c](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Absolute_positioning), when left is auto, the absolutely positioned box will appear exactly where it would have had if it wasn’t positioned, which means IE does it wrong and need a fix

Adding an inner wrapper, make it behave as an inline element (size adjust to content), set it to position relative and you will get the wanted result cross browser.

```css
.overlay-single { 
  text-align:center;
}
.overlay-wrapper { 
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.overlay-single .top {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-single">
  <div class="overlay-wrapper">
    <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    <img class="bottom" src="https://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the solution and explanation. I know I'm new at this but at least I'm not going crazy.